# PDF.js displays PDF documents in really low resolution/ blurry almost. Is this how it is?

Tags: pdf.js

I am trying to use PDF.js to view PDF documents.  I find the display really low resolutions to the point of being blurry.  Is there a fix?

[image]

```
 // URL of PDF document
        var url = "https://www.myFilePath/1Mpublic.pdf";

        // Asynchronous download PDF
        PDFJS.getDocument(url)
          .then(function(pdf) {
            return pdf.getPage(1);
          })
          .then(function(page) {
            // Set scale (zoom) level
            var scale = 1.2;

            // Get viewport (dimensions)
            var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

            // Get canvas#the-canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');

            // Fetch canvas' 2d context
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // Set dimensions to Canvas
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Prepare object needed by render method
            var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport
            };

            // Render PDF page
            page.render(renderContext);
          });
```

Answer (score 17):

There are two things you can do. I tested and somehow it worked, but you will get a bigger memory consumption.

1. Go to pdf.js and change the parameter `MAX_GROUP_SIZE` to like `8192` (double it for example). Be sure to have your browser cache disabled while testing.
2. You can force the `getViewport` to retrieve the image in better quality but like, I don't know how to say in English, compress it so a smaller size while showing:

   ```js
   // URL of PDF document
   var url = "https://www.myFilePath/1Mpublic.pdf";

   // Asynchronous download PDF
   PDFJS.getDocument(url)
       .then(function(pdf) {
           return pdf.getPage(1);
       })
       .then(function(page) {
           // Set scale (zoom) level
           var scale = 1.2;

           // Get viewport (dimensions)
           var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

           // Get canvas#the-canvas
           var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');

           // Fetch canvas' 2d context
           var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

           // Set dimensions to Canvas
           var resolution =  2 ; // for example

           canvas.height = resolution * viewport.height; //actual size
           canvas.width  = resolution * viewport.width;

           canvas.style.height = viewport.height; //showing size will be smaller size
           canvas.style .width = viewport.width;

           // Prepare object needed by render method
           var renderContext = {
             canvasContext: context,
             viewport: viewport,
             transform: [resolution, 0, 0, resolution, 0, 0] // force it bigger size
           };

           // Render PDF page
           page.render(renderContext);
       }
   );
   ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me, I just needed to add `px` to the style.height and style.width.

Comment: Where to add px? I am having same problem and I tried this solution but not getting results. Can you please help me..

Comment: @MurtazaBharmal `canvas.style.height = viewport.height + 'px';` and  `sizecanvas.style.width = viewport.width + 'px';`

Comment: In my case, using a `transform` in the `renderContext` caused a misalignment with the text layer. Better to use `context.scale(resolution, resolution);`

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you, my issue was pdf was not rendering in crisp quality according with the responsiveness. So I searched, and modified my code like this. Now it works for rendering crisp and clear pdf according to the div size you want to give.

```js
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("your_pdfurl");

loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    console.log('PDF loaded');

    // Fetch the first page
    var pageNumber = 1;
    pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        console.log('Page loaded');

        var container = document.getElementById("container") // Container of the body
        var wrapper   = document.getElementById("wrapper");  // render your pdf inside a div called wrapper
        var canvas    = document.getElementById('pdf');
        var context   = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const pageWidthScale = container.clientWidth / page.view[2];
        const pageHeightScale = container.clientHeight / page.view[3];

        var scales = { 1: 3.2, 2: 4 },
        defaultScale = 4,
        scale = scales[window.devicePixelRatio] || defaultScale;

        var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var displayWidth =  Math.min(pageWidthScale, pageHeightScale);;
        canvas.style.width = `${(viewport.width * displayWidth) / scale}px`;
        canvas.style.height = `${(viewport.height * displayWidth) / scale}px`;

        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
        renderTask.promise.then(function() {
            console.log('Page rendered');
        });
    });
}, function(reason) {
    // PDF loading error
    console.error(reason);
});
```

Comment: Hi Snehil, thanks for answering and joining Stack Overflow. Its a bit unclear from your answer what you actually did. Can you explain the logic? Is it something to do with drawing to a larger scale?

Comment: @O'Rooney in case still wondering https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10509#issuecomment-517009617

Comment: This worked well for me! The other solutions didn't. Thanks!